# prevent events from bubbling up in tinyMCE 4.5

Tags: jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE 4.5 on one of my game pages.

Using  the jQuery click event, when I click a `<div>`, the editor opens.  However, whenever I interact within TinyMCE, that jQuery click event fires again.

Is there a way to stop behavior?

I know in simple setups, you can use stopPropagation, but I don't see how you could use that with TinyMCE.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at using inline mode with TinyMCE?  It does effectively what you want without you having to write any JavaScript code to manage the opening and closing of the editor.

Comment: @MichaelFromin thanks but I need to use jQuery/ajax to load and save data to and from tinymce. I also have some custom buttons that I've defined.